# is there a working example for Regex constraint in symfony?

Tags: regex, symfony, constraints

have someone a working example for using Regex to check a digital or string values?

Comment: You question is unclear about what you're trying to achieve... Regex for PHP? HTML? JS? Java? And don't answer your own question if it's to complete it. Just edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, simply browse [the official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html).